# Problema con charsets en html

Tags: html, utf-8

Necesitaba aplicar una firma automática centralizada en un cliente. Lo que hice fué escribir un HTML con variables *NOMBRE* *PUESTO* *DIRECCION* etc.

Luego copio los archivos en genéricos al equipo por medio de una GPO y ejecuto un .vbs que realiza las siguientes funciones con código citado:

-Define variables tomando los datos del AD

-Predetermina este html como firma de outlook

```
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add()
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection

Set objEmailOptions = objWord.EmailOptions
Set objSignatureObject = objEmailOptions.EmailSignature

Set objSignatureEntries = objSignatureObject.EmailSignatureEntries

objSignatureObject.NewMessageSignature = "Empresa"
objSignatureObject.ReplyMessageSignature = "Empresa"


objDoc.Saved = True
objWord.Quit
```

-Abre el html y lo guarda en una variable tipo string

-Edita los campos genéricos por los datos reales de cada usuario con Replace

-Guarda los cambios utilizando formato utf-8

```
Save2File strNewText,appDataLocation+"\Microsoft\firmas\Empresa.html"

Sub Save2File (sText, sFile)
    Dim oStream
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    With oStream
        .Open
        .CharSet = "utf-8"
        .WriteText sText
        .SaveToFile sFile, 2
    End With
    Set oStream = Nothing
End Sub
```

Hasta aquí todo parecería normal, pero el cuerpo del html tiene dos componentes. La firma propiamente dicha; y un disclaimer con texto en español e inglés que me pidieron agregar.

La definición del charset en el html es la siguiente:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

Pero resulta que en este momento, sólo en el disclaimer me aparecen las tildes con caracteres extraños, como si el charset no los reconociera.

Con algunas modificaciones que hice pude invertirlo, es decir, el nombre o el sector en la empresa del personal me salía con errores en las tildas, pero el disclaimer salía bien!

Necesito unificarlo, y sea en utf-8 o iso-8859-1 lograr que tanto los datos del AD como el disclaimer se visualice correctamente con tildes y todo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el problema no esta en el charset del html,el problema es que cuando windows crea sus archivos tienen como codificación por defecto windows-1252. Por supuesto lo que pasa es que el html esta esperando datos en utf-8 y vienen en windows-1252. Revisa que cuando crees el archivo la codificación sea utf-8. Para cuambiar esa codificacion puedes usar notepad++ o cualquier IDE. Espero te sirva. Saludos

Comment: Te agradezco mucho la respuesta. Verdaderamente los charsets no son mi fuerte, y no es la primera vez que tengo dudas sobre caracteres extraños. No sabía de la existencia de windows-1252 y ya guardé los html en ISO-8859-1 porque logro la visualización perfecta que en utf-8 no me dá por alguna razón. Lo hice con Sublime Text. Muchas gracias!